# Queue ThreadPool

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ThreadPool and JobQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179399/threadpool-and-jobqueue)

1. Manager specifies the jobs into the job queue(Queue Size is not fixed).
2. Threads are maintained by fixed number of ThreadPool.
3. Whenever there is a job in job Queue, Frame assigns Threads from ThreadPool to the job.
4. If there is no Job in the Queue, Then the thread needs to wait until the job arrives. (Step 3 & 4 repeats on)

How may i implement these, if possible mention the code also.

Comment: [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) is all you want.

Comment: @AmitD - I was just about to post the same.  You should put it in as an answer.

Comment: You already asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179399/threadpool-and-jobqueue). Please do not create duplicates when the question has already been closed as not a real question. And please, read the API documentation !

Comment: @Pache - well spotted!  Voting to close this one.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to queue your task and [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with workers to process your tasks.

**Sample Source code:**

```
    final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    queue.put("test");// Add item here
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);// specifynumber
                                                                // of thread
            int numWorkers = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        service.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        String item = queue.take();
                        // Process item
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Explanation:**

> Manager specifies the jobs into the job queue(Queue Size is not fixed).

*Declare a blocking queue which will hold your Job. `String` type represent Job here.*

```
final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
```

> Threads are maintained by fixed number of ThreadPool.

*Use `ExecutorService` with `FixedThreadPool` size.*

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

> Whenever there is a job in job Queue, Frame assigns Threads from ThreadPool to the job.

*Submit the Jobs to queue using `put` operation.*

```
queue.put("test");
```

*Use `take()` operation which is blocking*

```
queue.take();//When there is job it will return the value else will get block
```

---

References:

- [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)
- [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: can you little bit extend with details

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ExecutorService to queue you tasks and manage your thread pool.

> Manager specifies the jobs into the job queue(Queue Size is not fixed).

Submit tasks to the ExecutorService to process each job, using `submit(Runnable)`

> Threads are maintained by fixed number of ThreadPool.

A `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n_threads)` is a fixed size thread pool

> Whenever there is a job in job Queue, Frame assigns Threads from ThreadPool to the job.

The ExecutorService will assign jobs to thread as they become free.

> If there is no Job in the Queue, Then the thread needs to wait until the job arrives.

Threads without a task are idle and have little impact on resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) from JDK if you are using JDK 5 or more. Your Jobs are implementations of Callable interface. ExecutorService is the facade into the executors.